Why is this not loading the plist file and not working in general
Help!!
I have the below script that I am trying to run from my MDM Kandji to remove a local admin account after a specified amount of time.
Both the executable and the plist file get created on the device just fine and I confirmed the executable works when I run it manually on the device. I have also confirmed the LaunchDaemons ownership and permissions are correct and verified the plist file syntax using plutil.
But I get the below error code when I run the script from my MDM Kandji.
• Exit code: 5
• Script results:
• Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
• An error occurred executing the item "Testing Removing Local Admin from Device": Script exited with non-zero status.
I have added exit 0 to the end of the script but I still get the error code "Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error"
Also, when I manually load the plist file on the deive with "launchctl load -w" it will load but then after 30 seconds it will have the status code of 1= "Operation not permitted".
I know the load command is depreciated but when I try to manually run launchctl bootstrap system com.example.deletetemp.plist I get "Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error"
I have been trying to figure this out for days and I dont know why it is not loading the service correctly and that I keep getting "Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error" and "Operation not permitted"
Any help would be great. thanks
#!/bin/bash

# Create the script
cat > /opt/deletetemp.sh << EOF
# Delete the user and its home directory
sudo dscl . -delete /Users/temp
sudo rm -rf /Users/temp
EOF

# Make the script executable
sudo chmod +x /opt/deletetemp.sh

# Create the LaunchDaemon plist
cat > /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.deletetemp.plist << EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.deletetemp</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/opt/deletetemp.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>30</integer> <!-- 30 seconds -->
  </dict>
</plist>
EOF

# Set permissions and ownership for the plist
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.deletetemp.plist
sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.deletetemp.plist

# Load the LaunchDaemon
sudo launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.deletetemp.plist

See other section
